# OSD not working on AOC q2770pqu monitor

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, osd

I have a newish AOC q2770pqu monitor and it has been working ok until today. I usually use it with a DP connection, but this morning I want to use it with HDMI. I couldn't get into the menu system to change the display setting from DP to HDMI. I kept messing around and managed to turn on something called "Clear Display" which is frankly horrible.

I am now able to change the input from HDMI to DP and other options by pressing the + button (it should be the Auto button), but the menu button, "-" button, and auto button do not work as they should.

The buttons themselves are ok I would assume as if I turn on the PC whilst holding down the menu button the OSD menu becomes "locked" which is expected behaviour - so the button physically works.

Is it possible to reset the monitor to factory settings (as in reload/reset the software) or update the firmware or any similar solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no user fix. AOC fixed the monitor free of charge.